# perl modules failing to install

Tags: cpan

I was writing a perl script and realised I needed to get some additional modules, so I used the command:

```
$ cpan List::MoreUtils
```

and got back:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 04 Jul 2022 15:56:10 GMT
Running install for module 'List::MoreUtils'
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
LWP failed with code[503] message[Service Unavailable]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
--2022-07-04 14:02:20--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)... 146.75.33.55, 2a04:4e42:79::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)|146.75.33.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2022-07-04 14:02:20 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440" "http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440'. Giving up on it.

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
--2022-07-04 14:02:21--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)... 146.75.33.55, 2a04:4e42:79::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)|146.75.33.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2022-07-04 14:02:21 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440" "http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
LWP failed with code[503] message[Service Unavailable]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
--2022-07-04 14:02:22--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)... 146.75.33.55, 2a04:4e42:79::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)|146.75.33.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2022-07-04 14:02:22 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440" "http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440'. Giving up on it.

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
--2022-07-04 14:02:23--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)... 146.75.33.55, 2a04:4e42:79::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)|146.75.33.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2022-07-04 14:02:23 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440" "http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(http://www.cpan.org/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o
conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
```

It's not like I've not downloaded other modules before.  I'm not sure what's going on.  Says "Service Unavailable 503".  Yet, I can go to the URLs stated in the log above directly with my browser and download the file.

Trying to use the `wget` command directly results in the same issue.

```
$ /usr/bin/wget -O "/c/users/ahawryluk/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz.tmp24440" "http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz"
--2022-07-04 14:22:41--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.430.tar.gz
Resolving www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)... 146.75.33.55, 2a04:4e42:78::311
Connecting to www.cpan.org (www.cpan.org)|146.75.33.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2022-07-04 14:22:41 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

I'm using MSYS2.  What could be going on here?  Is there something wrong with the cpan site?

### Edit

Things I've tried are:

1. Adding mirrors as shown [here](https://www.perl.com/article/44/2013/10/20/Find-CPAN-mirrors-and-configure-the-local-CPAN-mirror-list/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20a%20CPAN%20mirror,scheme%20(http%2C%20ftp).).
2. Attempted to do a full system upgrade as shown [here](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1822#issuecomment-333326232).
3. Tried to use a Ubuntu WSL to do the same thing.
4. <strike>Tried to use my phone's data network to confirm that it wasn't caused by a firewall issue.</strike>

No joy.

Can someone at least comment to say if they are having the same issues by doing a test module install?

Answer (score 0):

Grrr.  When I had attached to my phone, it's WiFi was connected to my local network and so had the same issue.  Once I put it to only the cell network, it worked fine.  Seems that this is caused by some change to our corporate firewall.

Still doesn't explain why I could get to the file directly through the browser but couldn't using `wget` though.